# Extract vector names conditionally in R

Tags: r, string, vector, char, extract

I'm trying to get the names of the elements in a vector with some priorities.

If there is any element with value `"integer"`, get the name of the first of such elements (in the example below, `year`)

But if there is no element with value `"integer"`, then do the same thing with any element with value `"numeric"`.

I have tried the following without success (*this is a toy example a functional answer is appreciated*):

```
cl <- c(group = "character", degree = "numeric", year = "integer", zoo = "integer")

names(cl[cl == "integer" || cl == "numeric"])[1]

desired.output = "year"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep`.

```
names(sort(cl[grep("integer|numeric", cl)])[1])
# [1] "year"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but there are two issues with your approach so far:

1. The `||` operator only works with one element; since you're looking over more than one you would want `|` instead. See `` ?`||` `` for more details.
2. Your approach would treat "integer" and "numeric" equally, rather than prioritising numeric as you would prefer.

One way of doing it would be:

```
Coalesce2 <- function(x, y) if(is.na(x))  y  else  x
Coalesce2(cl[cl == "integer"][1], cl[cl == "numeric"][1])
```

NB. The only reason I've made a new coalesce function here rather than using dplyr's is that that doesn't preserve names in the way I think you want.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a fixed match, we can use `%in%`

```
names(sort(cl[cl %in% c('integer', 'numeric')]))[1]
#[1] "year"
```

---

Or convert to `factor` with `levels` specified

```
names(sort(factor(cl, c('integer', 'numeric'))))[1]
#[1] "year"
```

---

Or with `match`

```
names(cl)[na.omit(match(c('integer', 'numeric'), cl))[1]]
#[1] "year"
```

Comment: Upvoted thanks. Have you also seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959700/extract-how-a-model-treated-each-predictor-as-factor-or-integer-in-r)?

Comment: @rnorouzian i posted a solution there.  the 'group' is not factor class